# Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recogned

Tags: c#, mysql, query-builder

In Query Builder my query is:

```
SELECT Id, BrojRacuna, Opis, Izdavatelj, DatumIzdavanja,
ValutaPlacanja, Iznos, Napomena, IF(Odobrenje = 0, 'Odobreno', 'Nije
odobreno') AS Odobrenje1,  OdobrenjeDatum FROM tblfinancije
```

But executing this code shows error:

> Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recogned.

What should I do to avoid this?

It's pretty weird because same query is tested and it works fine if doesn't run from Query Builder in .Net.

I'm working with MySQL 5.6 and C# 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with using `CASE`

```
SELECT Id, BrojRacuna, Opis, Izdavatelj, DatumIzdavanja, ValutaPlacanja, Iznos, Napomena,
(CASE WHEN Odobrenje = '0' THEN  'Odobreno' ELSE 'Nije odobreno' END ) AS Odobrenje1
, OdobrenjeDatum FROM tblfinancije
```

<kbd>[**See Fiddle with CASE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30e31/1)</kbd>

```
SELECT Id, BrojRacuna, Opis, Izdavatelj, DatumIzdavanja,
ValutaPlacanja, Iznos, Napomena, IF(Odobrenje = '0', 'Odobreno', 'Nije
odobreno') AS Odobrenje1,  OdobrenjeDatum FROM tblfinancije
```

<kbd>[**See Fiddle with IF**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30e31/3)</kbd>

Comment: Hm... now shows me error:

Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'END'.
Missing FROM clause.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'FROM'.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: The query is working but Query Builder of Visual Studio shows error. That's the problem. I don't know how it works and why doesn't accept that simple query.